# Phone nr access works in phone but crashes on tablet even with try/catch

Tags: android

I have an Android phone app that accesses the phone number for registration info like this:

```
    String thisPhoneNumber = "0";
    try {
        TelephonyManager tMgr=(TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        thisPhoneNumber = tMgr.getLine1Number(); }
    catch (Exception e) { }
```

It works fine on the phone. A friend tried it on the tablet (a recent one) and the app crashes. If I comment out the 4 lines of try/catch it works fine so it looks like the crash must be on the getSystemService call.

In a bit of searching stackoverflow, it sounds like code should run on either platform but that's not what I'm seeing.

Shouldn't the try/catch prevent the crash and allow the exception to be handled?

Is there some other way to allow the getSystemService to execute without crashing on the tablet? Or do I have to not make that call on the tablet?

Answer (score 0):

check with if statement check if of the variables in those 2-3 lines are null, and stop executing the code if so, for example

try
{
        TelephonyManager tMgr=(TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
if(tMgr!=null)
        thisPhoneNumber = tMgr.getLine1Number(); }
cath(Exception o)
{}

or you can try to find if the device is a tablet or phone(phone or non phone device)
and then execute two different statements in if code
if(phone) { the code}
or you can have abstract class  whit a function find phone number
and do some think like

```
if(device is phone)
{
  apstractClass=new phoneImplementation();
} else
{
  apstractClass= new nonPhoneImplementation();if (((TelephonyManager)getContext().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE)).getLine1Number()
== null)
```

{
    // no phone
} `enter code here`
    }
    thisPhoneNumber=apstarctClass.getPhoneNumber()

where phoneImplementation().getPhoneNumber() will have your code, the code from the question and   nonPhoneImplementation().getPhoneNumber() will return 0

you can check with this if a device has phone capabilities

```
if (((TelephonyManager)getContext().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE)).getLine1Number()
    == null)
{
    // no phone
}
```

My opinion is that this will solve your problem:

```
String thisPhoneNumber = "0";
try
{
    if (((TelephonyManager)getContext().getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE)).getLine1Number()
        != null)
    {
         thisPhoneNumber = tMgr.getLine1Number();
    } }
catch(Exception o)
{}
```